# Error when creating a second instance of a custom class of a keras model

Tags: python, keras, neural-network

I have this implementation of my custom class of a Keras model:

```py
class PINNNetwork(keras.Model):
    def __init__(self,
                 inputs=2,
                 hidden_layers=[8,16,16,512],
                 output=1,
                 activation='tanh',
                 w_initializer='he_normal', b_initializer='zeros',
                 **kwargs
                 ):

        super(PINNNetwork, self).__init__(**kwargs)

        self.model_input = None
        self.model_hidden = []
        self.concat = []
        self.model_output = None

        self.model_input = keras.Input(shape=(inputs,))
        for layer_size in hidden_layers:
            self.model_hidden.append(
                Dense(layer_size,
                      activation=activation,
                      kernel_initializer=w_initializer,
                      bias_initializer=b_initializer)
            )
            self.concat.append(keras.layers.Concatenate())

        self.model_output = layers.Dense(output)

        self.inputs = self.model_input
        self.outputs = self.call(self.model_input)

        super(PINNNetwork, self).__init__(
            inputs = self.inputs,
            outputs = self.outputs,
            **kwargs
        )

    def call(self, inputs, training=None, mask=None):
        Z = inputs
        for layer, concat in zip(self.model_hidden, self.concat):
            Z_ = layer(Z)
            Z = concat([Z_, Z])
        return self.model_output(Z)
```

When I instantiate it once, everything works fine, but if I try to instantiate it a second time, I get an error, as if my `__init__` was different.

Where is the error? I know that if I remove the last call to `super().init` and the new `build` method, the problem is resolved, but without them, the model graph is not built, so I would like a solution that maintains the construction of the graph so that the `summary` and `plot_model` still work.

For this:

```py
network = PINNNetwork()
print("Network 1: ", network)

network2 = PINNNetwork()
print("Network 2: ", network2)
```

Returns:

```
Network 1:  <__main__.PINNNetwork object at 0x000001F6AE5C8AF0>
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[3], line 4
      1 network = PINNNetwork()
      2 print("Network 1: ", network)
----> 4 network2 = PINNNetwork()
      5 print("Network 2: ", network2)

Cell In[2], line 11, in PINNNetwork.__init__(self, inputs, hidden_layers, output, activation, w_initializer, b_initializer, **kwargs)
      2 def __init__(self,
      3              inputs=2,
      4              hidden_layers=[8,16,16,512],
   (...)
      8              **kwargs
      9              ):
---> 11     super(PINNNetwork, self).__init__(**kwargs)
     13     self.model_input = None
     14     self.model_hidden = []

File ~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\trackable\base.py:205, in no_automatic_dependency_tracking.<locals>._method_wrapper(self, *args, **kwargs)
    203 self._self_setattr_tracking = False  # pylint: disable=protected-access
    204 try:
--> 205   result = method(self, *args, **kwargs)
    206 finally:
    207   self._self_setattr_tracking = previous_value  # pylint: disable=protected-access

TypeError: Functional.__init__() missing 2 required positional arguments: 'inputs' and 'outputs'
```

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to create the model's input and output layers in the `__init__` method, then you're immediately trying to define the model's inputs and outputs again in the second call.

lets remove the first call to `super(PINNNetwork, self).__init__`

```
class PINNNetwork(keras.Model):
    def __init__(self,
                 inputs=2,
                 hidden_layers=[8,16,16,512],
                 output=1,
                 activation='tanh',
                 w_initializer='he_normal', b_initializer='zeros',
                 **kwargs
                 ):

        super(PINNNetwork, self).__init__(**kwargs)

        self.model_hidden = []
        self.concat = []

        self.model_input = keras.Input(shape=(inputs,))
        for layer_size in hidden_layers:
            self.model_hidden.append(
                Dense(layer_size,
                      activation=activation,
                      kernel_initializer=w_initializer,
                      bias_initializer=b_initializer)
            )
            self.concat.append(keras.layers.Concatenate())

        self.model_output = layers.Dense(output)
        
    def call(self, inputs, training=None, mask=None):
        Z = inputs
        for layer, concat in zip(self.model_hidden, self.concat):
            Z_ = layer(Z)
            Z = concat([Z_, Z])
        return self.model_output(Z)

# Test
network = PINNNetwork()
print("Network 1: ", network)

network2 = PINNNetwork()
print("Network 2: ", network2)
```

Comment: This works fine, but when `build`, the layers output shapes becomes "multiple", i need way to build correclty for a complete correct summary. Layers summary looks like this:  `dense_1 (Dense)             multiple                  176`

Comment: Try to build your model explicitly with the build(input_shape) function